# This is my third question, yet I still don't have a Student badge

Tags: discussion

This is my third question, but for some reason, I don't yet have a Student badge on my account. Why don't I have one yet?

This is my dashboard:

[image]

Comment: How to do it? i do not know how i can migrate or delete the question.

Comment: tnx, sorry, i just start use it normaly.

Comment: @pomsky Flagged as need of moderator intervention requesting migration to meta.

Comment: @DenisRohlinsky +1 to help you on your student badge journey :)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Really? +1 for an obviously off topic question on main? There is being nice and then just voting for any old crap, just my opinion but that is not good voting, why not vote on one of the OP`s actual questions?

Comment: @MarkKirby A large percentage of new users sign on for a few days and are never seen again. I think new users that stay on breathe extra life into the community. If a simple up-vote in their initial period keeps them engaged and coming back it's a small price to pay. I'm not a serial up-voter thought, ie I do down-vote as well and my up-votes given compared to votes received are probably within norms.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix My point is more, why choose this off topic post (that was migrated, nullifying your vote) to vote on? OP has 3 proper ones to vote on, why not vote on them? I am not having a go, your votes, your choice, just confused why you would pick this off topic post to vote?

Comment: @MarkKirby Hind sight is 20-20 and I wish I would have thought of that yesterday. FTR IIRC I did flag the question requesting a moderator to migrate the question from AU to meta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [the Badges page](https://askubuntu.com/help/badges), the Student badge is for "First question with score of 1 or more".

All of your questions have a score of zero (see the number to the left of each question in the image you included in your question), so you don't have one with a score of one or more.